# Should all of my clickable content be wrapped in either <a> or <button> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want more clarification on this: I have a website that uses a ton of JavaScript buttons styled with CSS like this:

```css
nav ul { font-size:150%; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0 }
nav li {
  width:150px; height:150px; list-style:none; float:left; margin:5px;
  -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none
}
nav li:hover { background:#022; color:#eee; cursor:pointer; } 
nav li:active { background:#066; color:#fff }
nav span {
  display:block; position:relative; top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%); transform:translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><span>one</span></li>
    <li><span>two</span></li>
    <li><span>three</span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Is it better semantically, functionally, etc. to use anchor tags instead like this, and why?:

```css
nav ul { font-size:150%; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0 }
nav li {
  width:150px; height:150px; list-style:none; float:left; margin:5px;
  -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none
}
nav li:hover { background:#022; color:#eee; } 
nav li:active { background:#066; color:#fff }
nav span {
  display:block; position:relative; top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%); transform:translateY(-50%)
}
nav a{ text-decoration:none; color:#222 }/* anchor styling added */
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href="#"><li><span>one</span></li></a><!-- anchor tags added -->
    <a href="#"><li><span>two</span></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><span>three</span></li></a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

what about using the `button` element instead of the other ways? Is there any difference?

Comment: Personally I'd go for the least markup you could... BTW, your last example is broken.. the `<a>` should be inside the `<li>`.  In all cases, the `<span>` isn't needed at all.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Why should I not use the anchor around the `li`? Also,  I too opt to use less markup where I can, but is this the best practice here? What about screen readers and browsers with JavaScript deactivated,  Is it big deal?

Comment: The `li` needs to be the direct child of the `ul'.  That's basic valid HTML rules.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I believe the `<a>` can go outside the `<li>` ... Yeaa, its not semantically great, but it shouldn't get you in trouble. Although yes, I'd put the `<a>` inside the `<li>` and make it fill the parent with CSS, if that's the desired result.

Comment: `<a>` and `<button>` have different purposes. Use `<a>` for links to other pages and `<button>` for forms or other actions that fire on click. Also, most search engines crawlers (except for Google and I don't know if it can in every case) cannot follow buttons onclick as hyperlinks.

Comment: Also you can't right click open in new window/tab on a button, you can on a link.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the `<a>` tags inside the `<li>` tags. Before HTML5, wrapping block elements (`<p>`), with inline elements (`<a>`) , would be considered invalid HTML. But since HTML5 is pretty globally adopted, it shouldn't be a issue. It's better semantically, but in terms of actual HTML, it's completely fine either way.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul but permitted contents of UL have not changed. "Permitted content: zero or more <li> elements, eventually mixed with <ol> and <ul> elements."

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use anchor tags because it's semantically the correct way to do it. It's better for accessibility because screen readers know that it's a clickable element, and the user is able to focus to it by tabbing.

Place the `a` tag as a child of the `li` tag.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>one</span></a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Typically you use `a` to link to other documents or parts of the application and you use `button` to perform some kind of action.